# How to preprocess tensorflow imdb_review dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, preprocessing

I am using [tensorflow imdb_review dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/imdb_reviews), and I want to preprocess it using **Tokenizer** and **pad_sequences**

When I am using the **Tokenizer** instance and using the following code:

```py
tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'])
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequences=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['text'])

print(word_index)
print(sequences)
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

**What I've tried**

store dataset as dataframe and then iterate over the text column, and store it in a list, and then tokenize it.

```py
df = tfds.as_dataframe(ds.take(4), info)
# list to store corpus
corpus = []
for sentences in df['text'].iteritems():
  corpus.append(sentences)

tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
word_index=tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

But i'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How can I use the `text` column and preprocess it to feed it to my neural network?

Answer (score 0):

For TypeErrors it is always good to check the exact type of the variable causing issues, especially when troubleshooting TensorFlow and Keras:

```
print(type(df['text']))
```

`fit_on_texts` expects a list of string or similar, but you are providing a dictionary, so you'll want to convert accordingly. Example:

```
from typing import List, Dict

foo_dict: Dict[str, str] = {"one": "first sentence", "two": "second sentence"}
foo_list: List[str] = list(foo_dict.values())

print(foo_dict)
print(type(foo_dict))

print(foo_list)
print(type(foo_list))
```

Output:

```
{'one': 'first sentence', 'two': 'second sentence'}
<class 'dict'>
['first sentence', 'second sentence']
<class 'list'>
```

API docs will help here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#fit_on_texts

I'm using type annotations in the example above which I find helps troubleshooting and avoiding bugs.

Comment: thank you for your solution and help! I was able to solve my data preparing problem with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364139/how-to-preprocess-tensorflow-imdb-review-dataset/66367131#66367131)

Answer (score 0):

The column df['text'] was of type 'object', which was a byte type, so the pandas Series contained b"foo", etc. The only change to make was to decode the object using: **.str.decode('utf-8')**

```
df = tfds.as_dataframe(ds.take(4))
reviews = df['text'].str.decode("utf-8")
corpus = reviews.tolist()
print(corpus)
tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
word_index=tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

I ran this and can confirm it works. The answer from Andre helpfully points out, look at the data types, especially when switching between TensorFlow/Keras and Pandas/Numpy APIs.